# how to run pipelines for CI/CD for a specific branch (dev)

Tags: continuous-integration, pipeline, cd, bitbucket-pipelines

I am using the below-mentioned code as my  'bitbucket-pipeline.yml' file

```
image: node:6.9.4
pipelines:
   branches:
      dev:
         - step:
            script:
               - npm install
```

At the time of committing the code and pushing to my dev branch, it's not getting triggered to my Pipeline dashboard.